# Aggregate including all levels?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have an R data frame with factor and numeric columns, and I would like to calculate certain summaries of the numeric columns by various groupings of the factors. In particular, I would like to be able to summarise by multiple combinations of the factors at once, and return the results in a single object.

For example, say I'm using the `warpbreaks` data frame, which has columns breaks (integer), wool (factor with levels "A", "B") and tension (factor with levels "L", "M" and "H"). If I want to get the average number of breaks for each combination of wool and tension, I know I can use `aggregate(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks, mean)` and it will give me something like:

```
  wool tension   breaks
1    A       L 44.55556
2    B       L 28.22222
...
6    B       H 18.77778
```

But I'd like to also calculate the means across just wool, and just tension, and for the dataset as a whole, and return something like:

```
  wool tension   breaks
1   NA      NA 24.14815
2   NA       L 36.38889
...
5    A      NA 31.03704
...
7    A       L 44.55556
...
12   B       H 18.77778
```

I tried a few variations of formulas in the aggregate function and couldn't find anything suitable, is this something that can be done simply?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an arbitrary number of inputs that you want to treat as a whole + individually, you can set up a loop via `Map`:

```
## set formula inputs
rhs <- c("wool","tension")
lhs <- "breaks"

## map it
Map(
  \(d,l,r) aggregate(d[l], d[r], FUN=mean),
  list(warpbreaks),
  list(lhs),
  c(list(rhs), rhs)
)

#[[1]]
#  wool tension   breaks
#1    A       L 44.55556
#2    B       L 28.22222
#3    A       M 24.00000
#4    B       M 28.77778
#5    A       H 24.55556
#6    B       H 18.77778
#
#[[2]]
#  wool   breaks
#1    A 31.03704
#2    B 25.25926
#
#[[3]]
#  tension   breaks
#1       L 36.38889
#2       M 26.38889
#3       H 21.66667
```

You can extend the `rhs` inputs however you see fit for many combinations, e.g.:

```
rhs <- 1:3
c(list(rhs), combn(rhs, 2, simplify=FALSE), rhs)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 2 3
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 1
#
#[[6]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[7]]
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate `aggregate` separately and combine them with `bind_rows`.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(aggregate(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks, mean),
                 aggregate(breaks ~ wool, data = warpbreaks, mean),
                 aggregate(breaks ~ tension, data = warpbreaks, mean))

#   wool  tension breaks
#   <fct> <fct>    <dbl>
# 1 A     L       44.556
# 2 A     M       24    
# 3 A     H       24.556
# 4 B     L       28.222
# 5 B     M       28.778
# 6 B     H       18.778
# 7 A     NA      31.037
# 8 B     NA      25.259
# 9 NA    L       36.389
#10 NA    M       26.389
#11 NA    H       21.667
```

Or in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(
  warpbreaks %>% group_by(wool, tension) %>% summarise(breaks = mean(breaks), .groups = 'drop'), 
  warpbreaks %>% group_by(wool) %>% summarise(breaks = mean(breaks)),
  warpbreaks %>% group_by(tension) %>% summarise(breaks = mean(breaks))
  )
```

---

For any number of inputs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

cols <- c('wool', 'tension')

map_df(seq_along(cols), function(x) combn(cols, x, function(y) {
  warpbreaks %>% group_by(across(all_of(y))) %>% summarise(breaks = mean(breaks))
}, simplify = FALSE) %>% bind_rows())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know a simple way to generalise this to any number of factor columns? Once there are more than 2 or 3 columns the combinations become pretty messy to enumerate by hand.

Comment: Sure, I added an update to do it for any number of column inputs.